# Find the common values in two columns and extract the corresponding value in third column in R studio

Tags: r

I have a data set with 3 columns and I want to create two data sets with common values in first and second columns with corresponding value in second column and another dataset with uncommon values  with correspond values in second column.

structure(list(col1 = c("F1:19911", "F6:29731", "F2:26353", "F2:11604",
"F1:20748", "F6:25287", "F2:19148", "F4:20479", "F3:19564", "F4:29795",
"F1:32641", "F1:23920", "F2:37051", "F4:31963", "F1:27075", "F1:34085",
"F1:31602", "F2:28123", "F2:28512", "F4:31963", "F6:19142", "F6:21309",
"F2:11153", "F2:20275", "F2:31059", "F2:3199", "F2:31759", "F2:18603",
"F4:21551", "F1:14042", "F2:25183", "F2:15691", "F2:17735", "F3:22580",
"F4:23956", "F3:29087", "F3:2604", "F1:18485"), col2 = c(99,
99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99,
99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99,
99, 99, 99, 99, 99), col3 = c("F1:45496", "F6:49991", "F1:42766",
"F6:41131", "F1:49777", "F1:48389", "F3:40668", "F1:51123", "F6:49282",
"F6:38250", "F1:59546", "F6:38404", "F1:40600", "F6:25287", "F2:19148",
"F1:31602", "F2:28123", "F1:19911", "F6:45844", "F1:40519", NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -38L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

I want out put to look like this:
dataset 1:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| F6:11249 | 85 |
| F6:17709 | 89 |

dataset 2:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| F5:14398 | 90 |

Basically I want to find common values in col1 and 3 and get the values in 2. same as we do in excel with conditional formatting find the common values and filter the col 1 to get common values and unique values with corresponding values in col2. But as the data set is very big excel is taking too long to filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit

I did understand what you are trying to do. You can :

1. Make a list of the values you have in col3

   `library(dplyr)`

   `value_list=data$col3 %>% as.factor() %>% levels()`
2. Check if you encounter these values in your col1, in order to find your common values

   `duplicated_data= data %>% filter(col1 %in% value_list) %>% select(col1,col2)`
3. Find your "unique" values by substracting the two datasets

   `unique_data= data %>% anti_join(duplicated_data,by="col1") %>% select(col1,col2)`

Comment: Basically I want to find common values in col1 and 3 and get the values in 2. same as we do in excel with conditional formatting find the common values and filter the col 1 to get common values and unique values with corresponding values in col2. But as the data set is very big excel is taking too long to filter.

Comment: Okay, so the code should be appropriate. Basically, you create two datasets : one when the values in col1 are the same than in col3 and the other when it is different. Then, you keep only col1 and 2.

Comment: It is not working for duplicated values. I am getting 0 hits. but when I run intersect command I get many hits. It is working for unique values though.

Comment: It works on clean data. The problem is probably that your two columns are not exactly the same. You could try : i) putting the two columns in the same format by doing  `data$col1=as.character(data$col1)` and same for col2 ii) remove unecessary spaces by doing `data$col1=gsub(" ","",data$col1)` and same for col2.

Comment: However, it is weird that one command works well and not the other. Are you sure that no duplicated values are in the second dataset ? (you can see that by doing `View(unique_data)` and then clicking on the col1's name, to order it).

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I have tried and it is not working. I have data over 3M rows. when I give intersect(df$col1,df$col3) I get 40k hits whereas with duplicated_data= data %>%filter(col1==col3) %>%select(col1,col2) I get 0 hits.

Comment: Does this work `data[data$col1 %in% intersect(data$col1,data$col3),(1:2)]`  ? What is the format of your data ? Use `class(data)` and `str(data)` to know

Comment: When I use 'class(data)' I get "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame". And when I tried using 'data[data$col1 %in% intersect(data$col1,data$col3),(1:2)]' it did not give the correct values. It giving a list quite more number of  proteins in col2 than expected.

Comment: And I found out that `unique_data= data %>%
   filter(col1!=col3) %>%
   select(col1,col2)`  is giving some numbers but it also not correct I tried it with smaller dataset in excel.

Comment: I think it is specific to your data, because both solutions work on the example I added to your post. It possible that you give an sample of your data ? Using `data %>% head(n=20L) %>% dput()` (and making sure there's both duplicated and unique values)

Comment: Thank you very much for patiently replying me. I have tried to mimic my data in the attached data with the command you have sent me. May be I not very clear what I exactly need. The values in col2 corresponds to col1. I want to find common rows in col1 and col3 and want the out put from col1 with corresponding values in col2 and same for unique rows in col1.

Comment: I have edited my dataset in question.

Comment: In your example, you don't have any duplicated values between col1 and col3. You do have 1/3 of NA's in your third column. Could it be an upload problem ? How do you upload your data in R ?

Comment: Or mabye I didn't understand what you need. Do you need to find duplicated values only in col1 ? In that case, try `duplicated_data= data %>% group_by(col1) %>% mutate(n=n()) %>% filter(n>1) %>% select(col1,ncol2)` and tell me if it is what you want

Comment: My actual data looks like this with uneven column size. And in example there are 5 duplicated values in col1 and col3 (F6:25287,F2:19148,F1:31602,F2:28123,F1:19911)

Comment: I can find duplicates with excel in col1 and col3. I am not sure how to send the screenshot.  F6:25287,F2:19148,F1:31602,F2:28123,F1:19911 these rows are duplicated in col1 and 3. now I want a list with these 5 duplicated rows and their corresponding value in col2. and remaining unique rows in col 1 with corresponding values in col2.

Comment: Okay, i didn't understand what you wanted. I edited my post. It is weird that `data[data$col1 %in% intersect(data$col1,data$col3),(1:2)]` could not do it, because it works on the example. But maybe it created duplicated rows.